# Unable to clone canvas as it is tainted, html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, screenshot, html2canvas, capture

I am stuck at this issue. [Tainted Canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyUDS.png), when I am clicking my Snapshot button inside my HTML, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I31v.png), I already tried adding crossorigin="anonymous" on my script.
This is my button function

```
$('#snap').click(function () {
html2canvas(document.getElementById("sfs-page"), {
onrendered: function(canvas) {
var tempcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
tempcanvas.width=465;
tempcanvas.height=524;
var context=tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(canvas,465,40,465,524,0,0,465,524);
var link=document.createElement("a");
link.href=canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
link.download = 'screenshot.jpg';
link.click();
window.open(link);
}
});
});
```

whenever I click my button I am getting that error. I am just using basic HTML codes. My sfs-page is the whole div and the canvases that are tainted are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using allowTaint html2canvas option :

```
html2canvas(el, {
  useCORS: true,
  allowTaint: true,
}).then(() => ...);
```